Astrojs - Google Map embed
I want to embed google map into my astro app.
i found this site give a tutorial and follow the instruction.
However I got errors:
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Uncaught (in promise) InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function

I am not sure how to debug this.
below are my code in astro:
<Layout>
<div id="map"></div>
</Layout>
<script>
  function initMap() {
    // Set the coordinates for the center of the map
    var center = { lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194 };

    // Create a new Google Maps object
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: center,
      zoom: 13,
    });

    // Add a marker to the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: center,
      map: map,
    });
  }
</script>
<script
  async
  defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxsxxxxxxxx&callback=initMap"
></script>

<style>
  /* Set the height of the map container */
  #map {
    height: 400px;
  }
</style>

which layout tag is just some header and footer stuffs. How can I resolve this?

just remove the async from your script tag and it should work
